# Need to compare Date & Year between dates

Tags: sql-server

In database, I have a varchar field which saves only year and month of Date as 2016/10. Now in asp.net, I'm selecting 2 dates and want to fetch the records between those two dates. I had written a SP to retrieve this as below

```
select * 
from   Bulk_Requires 
where  CreatedDate between convert(varchar(15),datepart(YYYY,@startdate))
                           + '/'
                           + convert(varchar(15),datepart(MM,@startdate)) 
                   and 
                           convert(varchar(15),datepart(YYYY,@enddate))
                           + '/'
                           + convert(varchar(15),datepart(MM,@enddate)))
```

But I'm getting the output wrongly. When I tried the below query it is working fine (static dates).

```
select * from Bulk_Requires where CreatedDate between '2016/01' and '2016/05'.
```

Can you please help on this, to get the results dynamically.

Comment: please tag your sql-server version

Comment: which field type is used to store ` 2016/10`, varchar?

Comment: Since the parameters are coming in to the SP, I would put that convert function at the top of the SP, not as part of the `Where` clause.

Comment: The crux of your problem is right here..."I have a date field which saves only year and month as 2016/10". That is NOT a date field. It is a string representation of a date and it a pain to deal with. You should use the date datatype here instead of this string. To do this correctly you should turn your database into a date instead of trying to twist an actual date into a string.

Comment: The issue that you are running into also, is the `DatePart` function will return a `1` for January, not a `01` that you are looking for. Same for May, it will return a `5` not a `05`, so your dates are `2016/1` and `2016/5`, not `2016/01` and `2016/05`.

Comment: @McNets, yes, it's varchar type in SQL and the version currently I'm using is 2016.

Comment: @Sean Lange: the database was created way back in 2003, So I can't change the datatype now, as it has huge data in that. Is there any alternate?

Comment: @WEI_DBA: Tried that (convert function at top) too, but it didn't worked

Comment: CreatedDate is datetime field?

Comment: @Kannan, no, it's a varchar

Comment: Do a test in your stored proc to verify the values you obtain, printing or selecting `convert(varchar(15),datepart(YYYY,@startdate))
                           + '/'
                           + convert(varchar(15),datepart(MM,@startdate))`

Comment: If I had a penny for every question that is having massive issues because of using varchars to represent dates I could retire wealthy. I don't know why so many people think it is ok to do this. Those same people would freak out if somebody stuck an int in a character datatype. So strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do int conversion and check as below

```
select * 
from   Bulk_Requires 
where Convert(int,replace( CreatedDate,'/',''))  between Convert(int,CONVERT(varchar(6), @Startdate,112)) 
    and Convert(int,CONVERT(varchar(6), @enddate,112))
```

Comment: what type variables I need to take for startdate & @enddate in SP? Varchar or Date? or any other?

Comment: Currently it is datetime rite, leave that as-is

Comment: Got it... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The BEST way to fix this is to fix the database but it is a legacy system so that isn't always possible. You also should avoid using the shortcuts in date functions as they are difficult to remember and the actual names make it far more clear.

You could tweak your query slightly like this so you always get 2 characters for the month.

```
select * 
from   Bulk_Requires 
where  CreatedDate between convert(varchar(15),datepart(Year, @startdate))
                           + '/'
                           + right('0' + convert(varchar(15),datepart(Month, @startdate)), 2)
                   and 
                           convert(varchar(15),datepart(Year, @enddate))
                           + '/'
                           + right('0' + convert(varchar(15),datepart(Month, @enddate))), 2)
```

Comment: Getting the below error Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Got it... Thank you